# Difference between the use of 'get' and 'make' in causatives

Tags: grammar

In my childhood I was told by my teacher that the causative made with 'get' and 'make' differ. He said that when we use 'get' it gives kind of sense as if the performer is forced to do the thing. Is this write? Is  there any difference between these two:

---

I made him clean the room.

---

I got him to clean the room

Answer (score 5):

Yes, your teacher was correct that *"to **make** a person do something"* implies forcing them to do it. On the other hand,  *"to **get** someone to do something"* conveys more of a sense of asking or convincing them to do it. Although in many contexts, they can be used interchangeably.

On a side note, you said *"is this write?"* in your question. The correct spelling is "*is this **right***?". It is confusing because the two words sound the same, but have different meanings (that is, they are [homonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym)). You **[write](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/write)** words on paper with a pen. Something is **[right](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/right)** if it is correct.

Comment: I meant to write 'right' but wrote 'write'.

Comment: I jumble homophones when I'm typing sometimes, and I'm a native speaker. It's like when I touch-type I'm using the parts of my brain that deal with speaking aloud/hearing rather than reading and dealing with text.